# When is this.balance updated?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

Hello is it possible to execute this "multiplicate" function? Assume I put 1 ETH to the contract as an owner, but when a hacker sends 2 ETH to the multiplicate, this.balance becomes 3 at the beginning of the function and then it's always greater than the msg.value. I wonder if I am missing something.

```
contract Multiplicator
{
    address public Owner = msg.sender;

    function() payable{}

    function withdraw() payable public
    {
        require(msg.sender == Owner);
        Owner.transfer(this.balance);
    }

    function multiplicate(address adr) payable
    {
        if(msg.value >= this.balance)
        {        
            adr.transfer(this.balance+msg.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Question 1:  When is this.balance updated?**

The value of `this.balance` in payable methods is increased by `msg.value` before the body of your payable method executes.  If your contract has a starting balance of 1 and you pass in a `msg.value` of 2, the payable method will already have a `this.balance` of 3 when it executes.

**Question 2: Is it possible to [successfully] execute this `multiplicate` function?**

Yes. If the contract's initial balance is zero and you pass in a `msg.value` of zero, the function will most likely complete without error. I wrote "most likely", since if the receiving address is a contract, the receiving contract could still make it fail.

Your example, where the contract starts with 1 ether and you invoke  `multiplicate` with a `msg.value` of 2 ether, will also execute successfully, but the inner condition invoking `transfer` will be skipped over.  `this.balance` will jump to 3 before the body of `multiplicate` executes.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is add a state variable that keeps track of the contract's balance. That way you could do:

```
function multiplicate(address adr) payable
{
  require (contractBalance + msg.value <= this.balance); // The contract should have enough funds...
  if(msg.value >= contractBalance)
  { 
    contractBalance += msg.value;
    uint moneyToTransfer = contractBalance;
    contractBalance = 0;
    adr.transfer(moneyToTransfer);
  }
}
```

You would have to keep track of contractBalance each time you receive or transfer eth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think this update came along with solidity 0.6.0

```
this.balance
```

should be replaced with

```
address(this).balance
```

Hope this helps