# Can I rely on the fact that 'address(this).balance >= msg.value' is always true?

Tags: solidity, ether, balances

To my understanding, at the beginning of a `payable` function in a contract, an amount of `msg.value` ether is added to the contract's balance.

Therefore, the expression `address(this).balance >= msg.value` is always true.

Therefore, I can compute `address(this).balance - msg.value` without any risk of underflow.

Is that correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. When a payable function is invoked the contract balance `address(this).balance` will be increased by `msg.value` before any of your code is executed. Therefore both statements of yours are correct:

```
address(this).balance >= msg.value // Always true in payable function
address(this).balance - msg.value  // Never underflows in payable function
```

[Another answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/39315/39959) is confirming it too.

Comment: Just tried it, but I'll try to get some evidence in the docs..

Comment: Actually if you send ETH to an external address, then later in the same transaction I'm pretty sure `address(this).balance` will have decreased by the sent amount, while `msg.value` should have stayed the same (since the incoming message never changed). So yes, this could underflow. (Untested though.)