# Difference between msg.value and address(this).balance

Tags: solidity

I am a bit confused about the difference between **msg.value** and **address(this).balance**, I read some QnA here , like [this page.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52538/can-i-rely-on-the-fact-that-addressthis-balance-msg-value-is-always-true) From what I read, I understood that each time a payable function is called **address(this).balance** is incremented by **msg.value**. This is not the case for my code below, each time my payable function `receiveMoney`  is called my **address(this).balance** is same as **msg.value** , even on subsequent and consecutive calls `getBalance()` is always equal to `balanceReceived`.I expected that for instance, if 1 ether was sent when `receiveMoney()` is called **msg.value** should be 1 and **address(this).balance** should also be 1, then if `receiveMoney()` is called the second time with 2 ether sent, **msg.value** should become 2 while **address(this).balance** becomes incremented by **msg.value**(2) to 3. In my own case the second call returned **msg.value** as 3 and **address(this).balance** as 3 too. Please I need clarification on this.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.13;

contract SendMoneyExample{
uint public balanceReceived;

// this receiveMoney will recieve money from the address that called the smart contract to the 
//smart contract
function receiveMoney() public payable{
balanceReceived += msg.value;
}

function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
    return address(this).balance;
} 

 


}
```

Comment: I suspect you are not issuing a real transaction, but `call`ing the contract locally

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you explain? Am working with remix

Answer (score 1):

This code makes sense. I would expect *balancedReceived == address(this).balance*

In this instance, *msg.value* is the amount on top of the tx fees sent to the smart contract. The contract balance (*address(this).balance*) is getting incremented by *msg.value* then you increment *balancedReceived* by the same amount, so they should be equal.

Comment: You are right, I just noticed that. I am now convinced that address(this). balance>=msg.value.